# How to deal with "not installable" dependencies?

Tags: installation, apt, dependencies

I ran `sudo apt-get install -y unity-dictionary-lens` and received a warning of unmet dependencies:

> unity-dictionary-lens : Depends: unity-singlet (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installable

I found the package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-singlet) but could not install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should reference python-unity-singlet.  I can fix that pretty easily, but it has some other problems, right now it doesn't work at all even if you can install it.  In the future you should just file a bug about stuff like this.  Here's the relevant bug for this one:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/onehundredscopes/+bug/1030284

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, you haven't enabled the `universe` repository of Ubuntu, as [`unity-singlet`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-unity-singlet) is located there and not available in the main repository.

Check your settings in 'Software Sources' or modify you `/etc/apt/sources.list` accordingly in order to enable 'universe'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list` and saw that numerous lines ending with `universe` were uncommented.

Comment: If universe is enabled, then there might be other reasons for why apt has chosen to mark the package as not installable. For example, when your system has conflicting packages installed that prevents installing ``unity-singlet``. What is the output when installing the package manually from the repositories, i.e. ``sudo apt-get install unity-singlet`` (after purging your current one first)?

Comment: I get `Package 'unity-singlet' has no installation candidate`. I just checked Software Sources and see check marks on **main**, **universe**, **restricted**, and **multiverse**.

Comment: I overlooked some very important difference in my answer. I've located the binary  package ``python-unity-singlet`` instead of ``unity-singlet``. It seems your package ``unity-dictionary-lens`` is just broken and has a dependency on the source package name. Try to report this error to the package maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by gertvdijk in his answer, the control information in `unity-dictionary-lens` should have pointed to the dependency `python-unity-siglet`.

Doing this worked for me:

```
apt-get download unity-dictionary-lens  
mkdir unity-lens  
dpkg -e unity-dictionary-lens_0.2_all.deb unity-lens  
dpkg --extract unity-dictionary-lens_0.2_all.deb unity-lens  
dpkg-deb --build unity-lens  

sudo gdebi unity-lens.deb
```